# in pyodbc how do you get a single table from database as an object

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I've struggled through documentation and I don't really know how to get a single table from Database via *pyodbc*.

I know how to access table and all the values, but is there way to get a table as an object?

I tried this, but it doesn't seem nice (although it works):

```
conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:\\inkom\\makenet.mdb')
DB=conn.cursor()
Single_Table=DB.execute('SELECT * FROM Table_Name')
```

isn't there easier way like `DB.getTable('Name')` ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use cursor.tables(table=tablename, catalog=, schema=, tableType=)

you should read through the wiki: http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor